# SAS keyboard shortcut move between tabs

Tags: sas, keyboard-shortcuts

How could I move from the Code tab to the Output Data tab with the keyboard? See red arrows in picture.

I'm using SAS Enterprise Guide 8.2

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `Ctrl+Tab` and `Ctrl+Shift+Tab` to navigate forwards and backwards through the tabs.

(I'm using Enterprise Guide 7.1 but hopefully this still works for you.)

**Edit:**
From the SAS EG 8.1 accessibility options on [this page](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/egdoccdc/8.1/ega11y/ega11y.htm#p0cvddgy7m3yeun1q7cs7fxvukdp), `Ctrl+F6` and `Ctrl+Shift+F6` might be what is required.

Comment: That´s the usual one but it would move me to the tab on "Flux Processus" or "Start page". The tabs I want to move in are within the program.